# Homotopy operator

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the article "**Lie theory and the Chern-Weil homomorphism**" of A. Alekseev and Meinrenken on page 8 you have the following definition:

2.8.**Homotopy operators**. The space $L\left ( E,{E}' \right )$ of linear maps $\phi :E\rightarrow {E}'$ between differential spaces is itself a differential space, with differential $d\left ( \phi  \right )=d\circ \phi -\left ( -1 \right )^{\left | \phi  \right |}\phi \circ d$. Chain maps correspond to cocycles in $L\left ( E,{E}' \right )^{\overline{0}}$.

A homotopy operator between two chains maps $\phi _{0},\phi _{1}:E\rightarrow {E}'$ is an odd linear map $h\in L\left ( E,{E}' \right )^{\overline{1}}$ such that $d\left ( h \right )=\phi _{0}-\phi _{1}$.

Taking into account the definition given on page 6 of the same article:

2.5. A **differential space** (ds) is a super vector space $E$, together with a differential,i.e. an odd endomorphism $d\in End\left ( E \right )^{\overline{1}}$ satisfying $d\circ d=0$.

So $L\left ( E,{E}' \right )$ is a differential space, together with a odd endomorphism $d\in End(L\left ( E,{E}' \right )^{\overline{1}})$ satisfying $d\circ d=0$.

I want to know in which part of the definition 2.5 works

$d\left ( \phi  \right )=d\circ \phi -\left ( -1 \right )^{\left | \phi  \right |}\phi \circ d$. Chain maps correspond to cocycles in $L\left ( E,{E}' \right )^{\overline{0}}$.

Thanks for the help